# Simple way of fusing a few close points?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of points as such

```
points = [(-57.213878612138828, 17.916958304169601),
          (76.392039480378514, 0.060882542482108504),
          (0.12417670682730897, 1.0417670682730924),
          (-64.840321976787706, 21.374279296143762),
          (-48.966302937359913, 81.336323778066188),
          (11.122014925372399, 85.001119402984656),
          (8.6383049769438465, 84.874829066623917),
          (-57.349835526315836, 16.683634868421084),
          (83.051530302006697, 97.450469562867383),
          (8.5405200433369473, 83.566955579631625),
          (81.620435769843965, 48.106831247886376),
          (78.713027357450656, 19.547209139192304),
          (82.926153287322933, 81.026080639302577)]
```

They are as such when plotted in red:

[image]

I now want to **fuse the points that are near to each other** (circles together in black). By fuse, I mean **replace those points with one point that has the averages of their coordinates.**

I do understand **there are whole bunches of clustering techniques** there to do the similar jobs. However, as you can see this is a simple task, if I am able to tune the distance threshold. So I am **reluctant to use any** clustering techniques. **Just a simple solution would be enough.**

I am using Python, if it helps.

---

By near, I mean the euclidean distance between them is smaller than a threshold, which can be tuned by myself. So the right top two dots will not get circled.

Comment: It's not at all clear that this is an extremely simple task. You used human intelligence to make the black circles. Can you precisely define the "nearness", e.g. why the dots in the lower left are circled but the two dots in the upper right are not? Depending on what that criterion is, the task may or may not be simple.

Comment: the better way to do it is to use pearson correlation method

Comment: averaging based on distance would involve a _clustering technique_.  In any case you might want to check out shapely, which gives your points a `.distance()` method.

Comment: As the answers show there are many pitfalls, so "really simple" is not possible. One "still simple" algorithm might be creating a matrix of all pairwise distances, turn it into a boolean (greater/smaller cutoff), create lists of connected points (that may need to be merged into larger clusters) and _then_ do the averaging

Comment: Ok, I [implemented last comment's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19397736/321973) and it's just as bloated as I suspected...

Comment: So was any of the answers provided helpful?

Answer (score 8):

You can have a function, which given a distance d would fuse the points which are within distance d of a given point (by taking their average):

```
def dist2(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2

def fuse(points, d):
    ret = []
    d2 = d * d
    n = len(points)
    taken = [False] * n
    for i in range(n):
        if not taken[i]:
            count = 1
            point = [points[i][0], points[i][1]]
            taken[i] = True
            for j in range(i+1, n):
                if Dist2(points[i], points[j]) < d2:
                    point[0] += points[j][0]
                    point[1] += points[j][1]
                    count+=1
                    taken[j] = True
            point[0] /= count
            point[1] /= count
            ret.append((point[0], point[1]))
    return ret
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the most flawless answer so far (though respecting PEP8 and having [function names in lowercase](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) might be nice)

Comment: you could of course use a [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) to take care of dimensionality and it's implementation of `(p1-p2)**2`

Comment: Note that this isn't a stable algorithm. The output depends on which order you get the points in. That's probably OK, since the OP didn't really define "closeness" rigorously, but still.

Comment: oh, one pitfall: if a third point lies close to the second one but too far from the first one and the average of these two first points is too far from the third one, your algorithm will fail to include point three

Comment: yes, I know, but it's a starting point :) He said he didn't want clustering after all, which is the right way to do it.

Comment: SHouldn't it be `point[0] += points[j][0] point[1] += points[j][1]`?

Comment: Also, in my problem, sometimes I need to fuse three points together. I suppose your current algorithm can only deal with 2 right? AFAIK, I have to run this algorithm twice to deal with the 3-point-fuse cases right? Any elegant modification that will fix this, please? Thanks! :)

Comment: @mavErick As I stated, it _will_ average three points `p1,p2,p3` correctly _if_ `p1` is close enough to `p3`, which may depend on the ordering of the points. It's an edge case, but if `p2` is in the middle of the other two points and just barely at critical distance, this will misbehave. That's the compromise you have to accept, otherwise you _will_ end up using a clustering algorithm.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler  Thanks! Yeah, I understand I have to accept some compromise for simplicity. I tried to increas the threshold distance to fuse p1, p2, p3. Even if I increase the threshold to such an extent that some other points that are far away from each other are fused together! My remaining p and p3 are obviously nearer. I am not sure why this weird thing happens..

Comment: yes, it should be:
it be point[0] += points[j][0] point[1] += points[j][1]
sorry about the typo

Comment: @mavErick Ok, I took a go at [a more precise answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19397736/321973), but as you can see it bloated a lot compared to the other two answers

Comment: NB Dist2 -> dist2

Answer (score 3):

You could just give a radius limit and iteratively join points that are closer than that radius away. If your dataset is small enough, brute force may suffice:

```
def join_pair(points, r):
    for p, q in itertools.combinations(points, 2):
        if dist(p, q) < r:
            points.remove(p)
            points.remove(q)
            points.append(((p[0]+q[0]) / 2, (p[1]+q[1]) / 2))
            return True
    return False

while join_pair(points, R):
    pass
```

Comment: @optus the `return True` will cause the loop to terminate prematurely.

Comment: @HennyH, on purpose, dropping back into the outer loop. That's because I have no idea what itertools.combinations may do if the list changes under it.

Comment: having a `return` statement inside a loop (within a function (the only place it would be valid)) will cause the control flow to leave the function. `break` and `continue` are used to affect control flow in a `for` loop. This means this code will only merge *at most* one point.

Comment: The function joins a single pair of closest points, returning True; or returns False if no points can be joined. Maybe it could use a comment but it should work, and break is not good enough (different return value). The outer while loop keeps calling the function while there are points to join.

Comment: Renamed the function to make it explicit what it does.

Comment: I see one potential pitfall here: If three or more points are close together, your algorithm will treat their coordinates unequal in the averaging, since e.g. `x_avg = [(x_1+x_2)/2+x_3]/2 = (x_1+x_2+2*x_3)/4`

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That's true, but then the OP wasn't very clear about the requirements, so I cheated ;). You could add weights to the algorithm (start all at 1, sum on join, multiply in averaging) if you care.

Comment: Good point - OP has to decide on the trade-off, [simple _or_ accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it)

Comment: - and the tradeoff is a _lot_, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19397736/321973) blew up...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my *severly unoptimized* go at a slightly more complex algorithm, which first creates a boolean proximity matrix, from that a list of clusters which is ultimately used to obtain the averaged coordinates:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Oct 16 08:42:50 2013

@author: Tobias Kienzler
"""


def squared_distance(p1, p2):
    # TODO optimization: use numpy.ndarrays, simply return (p1-p2)**2
    sd = 0
    for x, y in zip(p1, p2):
        sd += (x-y)**2
    return sd


def get_proximity_matrix(points, threshold):
    n = len(points)
    t2 = threshold**2
    # TODO optimization: use sparse boolean matrix
    prox = [[False]*n for k in xrange(n)]
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        for j in xrange(i+1, n):
            prox[i][j] = (squared_distance(points[i], points[j]) < t2)
            prox[j][i] = prox[i][j]  # symmetric matrix
    return prox


def find_clusters(points, threshold):
    n = len(points)
    prox = get_proximity_matrix(points, threshold)
    point_in_list = [None]*n
    clusters = []
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        for j in xrange(i+1, n):
            if prox[i][j]:
                list1 = point_in_list[i]
                list2 = point_in_list[j]
                if list1 is not None:
                    if list2 is None:
                        list1.append(j)
                        point_in_list[j] = list1
                    elif list2 is not list1:
                        # merge the two lists if not identical
                        list1 += list2
                        point_in_list[j] = list1
                        del clusters[clusters.index(list2)]
                    else:
                        pass  # both points are already in the same cluster
                elif list2 is not None:
                    list2.append(i)
                    point_in_list[i] = list2
                else:
                    list_new = [i, j]
                    for index in [i, j]:
                        point_in_list[index] = list_new
                    clusters.append(list_new)
        if point_in_list[i] is None:
            list_new = [i]  # point is isolated so far
            point_in_list[i] = list_new
            clusters.append(list_new)
    return clusters


def average_clusters(points, threshold=1.0, clusters=None):
    if clusters is None:
        clusters = find_clusters(points, threshold)
    newpoints = []
    for cluster in clusters:
        n = len(cluster)
        point = [0]*len(points[0])  # TODO numpy
        for index in cluster:
            part = points[index]  # in numpy: just point += part / n
            for j in xrange(0, len(part)):
                point[j] += part[j] / n  # TODO optimization: point/n later
        newpoints.append(point)
    return newpoints


points = [(-57.213878612138828, 17.916958304169601),
          (76.392039480378514, 0.060882542482108504),
          (0.12417670682730897, 1.0417670682730924),
          (-64.840321976787706, 21.374279296143762),
          (-48.966302937359913, 81.336323778066188),
          (11.122014925372399, 85.001119402984656),
          (8.6383049769438465, 84.874829066623917),
          (-57.349835526315836, 16.683634868421084),
          (83.051530302006697, 97.450469562867383),
          (8.5405200433369473, 83.566955579631625),
          (81.620435769843965, 48.106831247886376),
          (78.713027357450656, 19.547209139192304),
          (82.926153287322933, 81.026080639302577)]

threshold = 20.0
clusters = find_clusters(points, threshold)
clustered = average_clusters(points, clusters=clusters)
print "clusters:", clusters
print clustered

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for cluster in clustered:
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(cluster, radius=threshold/2, color='g'))
for point in points:
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(point, radius=threshold/2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none'))
plt.plot(*zip(*points), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
plt.plot(*zip(*clustered), marker='.', color='g', ls='')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: clustering...]

(For better visualization, the circles' radii are *half* the threshold, i.e. points are in the same cluster if their circles merely intersect/touch one another's edge.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_close_pts(pts, rad=5): # pts is a numpy array of size mx2 where each row is ( xy )
pts = np.float32(pts) # avoid issues with ints

# iteratively make points that are close to each other get closer ( robust to clouds of multiple close pts merge )
pts_to_merge = (np.sqrt(np.power(pts[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) - pts[:, 0].reshape(1,-1),2) + \
                   np.power(pts[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) - pts[:, 1].reshape(1, -1), 2))) <= rad

for _ in range(5):
    for pt_ind in range(pts.shape[0]):
        pts[pt_ind,:] = pts[pts_to_merge[pt_ind, :], :].reshape(-1, 2).mean(axis=0)

#now keep only one pts from each group. 
pts_to_merge = ((np.sqrt(np.power(pts[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) - pts[:, 0].reshape(1, -1), 2) + \
                        np.power(pts[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) - pts[:, 1].reshape(1, -1), 2))) <= rad) * \
               (np.eye(pts.shape[0])== 0)


for pt_ind in range(pts.shape[0]):
    if (pts[pt_ind,:] == 0).all() == False:
        inds_to_erase = pts_to_merge[pt_ind, :]
        pts[inds_to_erase, :] = 0


return pts[(pts==0).all() == False, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple but may require some Python libraries, this method can be applied for both 2d/3d points.

- Find the closest point.
- Use the average to replace these points.

**Substep:**

- Find the closest point pairs.

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

points = [(-57.213878612138828, 17.916958304169601),
        # ... (rest of the points as in the original code)]

# threshold is the defination of close
threshold = 20.0

tree = KDTree(points)
rows_to_fuse = tree.query_pairs(r=threshold)

print('rows_to_fuse:', rows_to_fuse)
# rows_to_fuse: {(0, 7), (1, 11), (3, 7), (0, 3), (5, 6), (8, 12), (5, 9), (6, 9)}
```

- Put the closest pairs into groups.

For the above pairs, if they share an element, put them into the group. This is actually finding connected components in the graph.

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.components.connected import connected_components

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(rows_to_fuse)
components = list(nx.connected_components(G))

print('components:', components)
# components: [{0, 3, 7}, {1, 11}, {9, 5, 6}, {8, 12}]
```

- Add the single faraway points to the components.

```py
# flat_list is only used to add the single point to the components
flat_list = [x for xs in components for x in xs]
print('flat_list:', flat_list)

for i in range(len(points)):
    if i not in flat_list:
        components.append({i})

print('components:', components)
# components: [{0, 3, 7}, {1, 11}, {9, 5, 6}, {8, 12}, {2}, {4}, {10}]
```

- Average the components.

```py
import numpy as np

# use for-loop is the same, here just use short syntax
clusters = [np.mean(np.asarray([points[x] for x in component]), axis=0) for component in components]
print("clusters:", clusters)
# clusters: [array([-59.80134537,  18.65829082]), array([77.55253342,  9.80404584]), array([ 9.43361332, 84.48096802]), array([82.98884179, 89.2382751 ]), array([0.12417671, 1.04176707]), array([-48.96630294,  81.33632378]), array([81.62043577, 48.10683125])]
```

- Draw the final results.

```py
# 5. Draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
for cluster in clusters:
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(cluster, radius=threshold/2, color='g'))
for point in points:
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(point, radius=threshold/2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none'))
plt.plot(*zip(*points), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
plt.plot(*zip(*clusters), marker='.', color='g', ls='')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Final result looks the same as [Tobias Kienzler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397736/3608824)

[image]