# Fast fuse of close points in a numpy-2d (vectorized)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distance

I have a question similar to the question asked here:
[simple way of fusing a few close points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375675/simple-way-of-fusing-a-few-close-points). I want to replace points that are located close to each other with the average of their coordinates. The closeness in cells is specified by the user (I am talking about euclidean distance).

In my case I have a lot of points (about 1-million). This method is working, but is time consuming as it uses a double for loop.

Is there a faster way to detect and fuse close points in a numpy 2d array?

---

To be complete I added an example:

```
points=array([[  382.49056159,   640.1731949 ],
   [  496.44669161,   655.8583119 ],
   [ 1255.64762859,   672.99699399],
   [ 1070.16520917,   688.33538171],
   [  318.89390168,   718.05989421],
   [  259.7106383 ,   822.2       ],
   [  141.52574427,    28.68594436],
   [ 1061.13573287,    28.7094536 ],
   [  820.57417943,    84.27702407],
   [  806.71416007,   108.50307828]])
```

A scatterplot of the points is visible below. The red circle indicates the points located close to each other (in this case a distance of 27.91 between the last two points in the array). So if the user would specify a minimum distance of 30 these points should be fused.

[image]

In the output of the fuse function the last to points are fused. This will look like:

```
#output
array([[  382.49056159,   640.1731949 ],
   [  496.44669161,   655.8583119 ],
   [ 1255.64762859,   672.99699399],
   [ 1070.16520917,   688.33538171],
   [  318.89390168,   718.05989421],
   [  259.7106383 ,   822.2       ],
   [  141.52574427,    28.68594436],
   [ 1061.13573287,    28.7094536 ],
   [  813.64416975,    96.390051175]])
```

Comment: scipy.spatial.cKDTree is where it is at

Comment: What if I want to find points that are relatively close? This seems like a good read: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a large number of points then it may be faster to build a [*k*-D tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) using [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), then query it for pairs of points that are closer than some threshold:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

tree = KDTree(points)
rows_to_fuse = tree.query_pairs(r=30)    

print(repr(rows_to_fuse))
# {(8, 9)}

print(repr(points[list(rows_to_fuse)]))
# array([[ 820.57417943,   84.27702407],
#        [ 806.71416007,  108.50307828]])
```

The major advantage of this approach is that you don't need to compute the distance between every pair of points in your dataset.

Comment: can you pleas elaborate? Why is there a .pop() ? I tried on my dataset and I always get a resulting array of shape (2, 2).

Comment: @Mehdi `rows_to_fuse` is a Python `set` containing `(i, j)` tuples, where `i` and `j` are the indices of a pair of rows in `points` whose distance is < `r`. `rows_to_fuse.pop()` removes an arbitrary tuple from the set and returns it (in this case there's only a single tuple in the set), which I then cast a list and use to index into the rows of `pairs` to retrieve the x, y coordinates for that pair. The final result is a `(2, 2)` numpy array, but `rows_to_fuse` is a set. It might be clearer if I cast `rows_to_fuse` directly to a list.

Comment: Another line was missing for my case,     fused_scans = np.mean(fused_scans, 1)
this gets the mean of the pairs.

Comment: great answer, as a suggestion you can add the parameter `output_type='ndarray'` to the `query_pairs` call, to obtain the result in an array instead of a set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scipy`'s distance functions such as `pdist` in order to quickly find which points should be merged:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

d = squareform(pdist(a))
d = np.ma.array(d, mask=np.isclose(d, 0))
a[d.min(axis=1) < 30]
#array([[ 820.57417943,   84.27702407],
#       [ 806.71416007,  108.50307828]])
```

### NOTE

For large samples this method can cause memory errors since it is storing a full matrix containing the relative distances.

Comment: @Mehdi, thanks for your comments, indeed for large samples this will face memory issues, but still it is a useful asset. I updated the answer to address your remarks

Comment: Was just a hint to the OP's condition (about 1 million points)