# How to merge close points in 2d list python

Tags: python, numpy, voronoi, kdtree

I'm having troubles to merge close points for Voronoi diagram, here is the case:

1. I load a map from image
2. The map is converted to an array containing only points meaning obstacles
3. Voronoi diagram is computed from this array

Then is the problem that I have vertices inside "obstacles" as shown in image[image]

My idea is to convert obstacles containing many points to one point.

List of points look similar to this:

```
map = [[11, 29], [11, 30], [11, 31], [12, 28], [12, 29], [12, 30]]
```

I want to take a group of points and merge these points into one.

I've found this [Fast fuse of close points in a numpy-2d (vectorized)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985185/fast-fuse-of-close-points-in-a-numpy-2d-vectorized?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I Don't have any idea how to fuse these points taking into account obstacles which are not "point-shaped"

Comment: do you know how many obstacles will be there or how long the distance in a cluster or between clusters is?

Comment: answered bellow, but no I don't know count/shape/size it can vary in a large range

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to `map` as variable name, as there is a function with the same name. Your issue in genreal is to find clusters which is similiar to the issue in your link, but based on the data k-Dtree might not be great. I would recommend an other clustering algorithm from [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html):

- KMeans, if you know the amount of obstacles
- DBSCAN, if you know the maximal size of the obstacles

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, DBSCAN
import numpy as np

```
obstacle_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 3],[3,4]]
obstacle_array = np.array(obstacle_list) # for easier handling

#if you know the number of obstacles
number_of_obstacles=2
cluster_values = KMeans(n_clusters=number_of_obstacles).fit_predict(obstacle_array)
print(cluster_values) # those are the cluster MeanShift found

#if you know the maximal size of an obstacle
max_size_of_obstacle = 3
db_values = DBSCAN(eps=max_size_of_obstacle).fit_predict(obstacle_array)
print(cluster_values)# those are the cluster DBSCAN found
```

If you want it to be represented only by 1 point probably somewhere in the center) you can loop over the `cluster_values` to calcualte it. I would take mean of x and y values, but your data seems to be only integers so you might want to take something else.

Comment: Thank you, I will try DBSCAN, which might be better, the use-case is to create Voronoi diagram for navigation 2d from jpg/png map, and also the size/number/shape of obstacles can vary. I found that shapefile might be useful but still haven't found any open source project which can do conversion form image to shapefile

Comment: could you provide a full example file or a link? i think a .png map to the voronoi would be quite possible.

Comment: I quickly created a prototype, problem is that I have to manually get rounding radius value. I found that visibility diagram could be this what I look for, but there is also a problem with the clustering image, and getting all polygons corners described in the clockwise order. https://github.com/adamkrawczyk/image_to_voronoi  and visibility diagram: https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/packages/navigation/doc/algorithm.html#visibility-graph

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't get the voronoi package (tried what you put in the readme but cant find it on pip). however if found this algorithm that might helps you quite a bit: https://github.com/spwhitt/cclabel . it is not up to date so you have to rpelace the dependecy `import image, ImageDraw` to `from PIL import Image, ImageDraw`, but then it shows all the objects the right cluster